# AnzoGraph helm - SPARQL Query Port

Tags: sparql, kubernetes-helm, anzograph

I have [deployed Anzograph using Helm](https://docs.cambridgesemantics.com/anzograph/v2.2/userdoc/deploy-helm.htm), and have set the config value to enable the SPARQL Endpoint:

```json
azgSettings:
  enable_sparql_protocol: true
```

but the Services do not expose the expected port 7070 for SPARQL API access.

```
anzograph-anzograph                          ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                            12345/TCP                                      10s
anzograph-anzograph-db-lb                    LoadBalancer   172.20.164.162   internal-12345-abc.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com   5600:30415/TCP,5700:31206/TCP,7000:30959/TCP   10s
anzograph-anzograph-frontend-lb              LoadBalancer   172.20.73.121    internal-12345-abc.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com   443:31459/TCP,80:30356/TCP                     10s
```

*How do I access the SPARQL endpoint outside the cluster?*

None of the ports exposed via LoadBalancer appear to work. The Port `12345` is labelled as `dummy`, and doesn't seem to do anything. Querying the pod directly on 7070 (`kubectl port-forward pod/anzograph-anzograph-db-0 7070`) seems to get further but gives 400 errors and no logs.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

The SPARQL endpoint is available under a `/sparql` route on the frontend on port 80.
You can access it within the cluster using: `http://anzograph-anzograph-frontend-lb:80/sparql`, or to get temporary development access externally run:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/anzograph-anzograph-frontend-lb 8080:80
http://localhost:8080/sparql?query=XYZ
```

Comment: on https://anzograph-anzograph-frontend-lb:443/sparql
you should be able to use TLS as well